# how to create a pipeline in jenkins for spring boot microservices

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, jenkins, microservices

I have a spring boot project with 4 microservices (Eureka service registry, Config server, a Zuul gateway and a userservice) in one repository with a parent project where I have a docker-compose.yml which reads the Dockerfiles in the microservices project and uses the "application-docker.yml" and "bootstrap-docker.yml"

What I'd like to do is to trigger a jenkins pipeline after a commit in git so that it will compile and deploy the microservices in Docker. Eventually I'd like to have a production configuration that deploys the images in Kubernetes maybe AWS.

Now, in order to work, the microservices need to start in order:

1. configserver
2. eureka service registry
3. gateway , etc..

What is the best practise?

If I have separate repositories per microservice, I think I can figure it out. It should be easy to deploy a single microservice assuming that configserver and eureka service registry are already up and running, in reality they should never change.

If I have a single repository, and I keep developing new microservices, do I need to have separate jenkins file per microservices or can I have a jenkinsfile in the parent project and use docker-compose?
How does it work? Any articles online that can help (couldn't find any). Does it make sense?

Or do I need to look at Jenkins X ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using separate repositories for each microservice. You use microservices to prevent monoliths and have small well-defined services; it only seems appropriate to also separate them by space i.e. store them in separate repositories (making it for example easier to reuse one).

You would then have to provide a Jenkinsfile in each repo. These would be mostly identical.

If you want fast release cycles you could automatically deploy a single service upon release. 
Alternatively you could use an additional release train module that handles the full deployment.
In both cases I would use a docker-compose file that handles the interconnection between the services.
You can enforce the right order by using  'depends_on, links, volumes_from, and network_mode: "service:..."'. For a full reference see [the docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/).

If you want to keep your single repository your Jenkinsfile(s) would have to be quite hacky, I suppose... After each commit you would either

- build all modules --> monolithic behaviour
- somehow determine which modules have changed (e.g. looking at the git log) --> same behaviour as with multiple modules but very hackily

**The Docker-Compose File**

If you want to release all modules at a specific point of time you could use a Release Train module where the docker-compose.yml resides next to a Jenkinsfile. Then when you want to ship your application you can start this Jenkins-job.

If you want to ship each service as soon as it is released, independently from the others, you would need to access the docker-compose.yml from each module. You could do this manually (since the files won't change too often) or create a docker module that you use as a git-submodule in all your services.

We use a generic docker-compose.yml for this, where every version is replaced by a variable:

```
example-service:
  image: example.service:${EXAMPLE_SERVICE_VERSION}
```

Then to start that specific service in jenkins we use the command

```
export EXAMPLE_SERVICE_VERSION=1.1.1
docker-compose -p example-project -f docker-compose.yml up -d example-service
```

Comment: Assuming I have different repositories, where would the docker-compose be reside? At the moment, it's in the multi-module maven parent project. I run it from there and it will build and deploy on docker the microservices in order (using the wait-for-it.sh).

Comment: I ellaborated my previous answer, hope that helps :)

Comment: I assume that the docker-compose will only have the microservice image and maybe database or other microservices if it depends on those. Also, just to be sure.. by release train module do you mean a pipeline?  Thanks!

Comment: With _release train module_ I mean an additional git-module that consists (more or less) only of a Jenkinsfile for the according pipeline, the docker-compose file and some way to determine the desired versions of your respective docker images.
This way you have the overhead of explicitly setting the versions for each microservice but the advantage that you have full control over when you release which version of your product.